# How to pass multiple parameters to hyperledger-composer query?

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-composer

I'm still a beginner to blockchain development and i couldn't figure out what is wrong with my code here.

Simple what i want in here to query an asset using two parameters.

I even tried hard coding the values and it worked fine with one parameter queries.

Also it works fine using the rest-server.

```
**
* Vote transaction
* @param {org.evotedapp.biznet.GenerateElectionResult} result
* @transaction
*/

async function electionResult(result) {


var factory = getFactory();
var namespace = "org.evotedapp.biznet";    
var currentElection;

const votes = await query("getBallotsByElection", {election: 
"resource:org.evotedapp.biznet.Election#el892076"})  // this query works fine

return getAssetRegistry("org.evotedapp.biznet.Election")
        .then(registry => {
            var electionRegistry = registry.get(result.electionId);
            return electionRegistry
        })
        .then(election => {
            currentElection = election;
            var candidates = election.candidates
            const results = []; 
            for(let i = 0; i<candidates.length;i++) {

                var candidateVotes = query("getBallotsByElectionAndCandidate", {election: `resource:org.evotedapp.biznet.Election#${result.electionId} `,candidate:`${candidates[i]}`})
                var resultCount = factory.newResource(namespace, "ResultCount", result.electionId+i);
                resultCount.candidate = candidates[i];
                if(candidateVotes == []){
                    resultCount.votes = 0
                }else{
                    resultCount.votes = candidateVotes.length;
                }
                results.push(resultCount)

           }

            var voteCountCandidate;
            return getAssetRegistry("org.evotedapp.biznet.VoteCountCandidate")
                .then(registry => {
                    voteCountCandidate = factory.newResource(namespace, "VoteCountCandidate", "vcc_"+result.electionId);
                    voteCountCandidate.election = currentElection
                    voteCountCandidate.results = results;
                    return registry.add(voteCountCandidate)
                })
                .then(() => {
                    var voteCountCandidateEvent = factory.newEvent(namespace, "GenerateElectionResultNotification");
                    voteCountCandidateEvent.voteCountCandidate = voteCountCandidate;

                    emit(voteCountCandidateEvent);
                });
            })

}
```

Here is the query:

```
query getBallotsByElectionAndCandidate {

    description: "Select all ballots by election"
    statement:
        SELECT org.evotedapp.biznet.Ballot
            WHERE (election == _$election AND votedCandidate == _$candidate)
}
```

I want this query to return matching values to the candidateVotes. It fails the transaction and gives this error:

```
Error: Error trying invoke business network with transaction id 5f256b4ed096962a60e2753f611cad7d051abd4703dde36cb03da08b14036788. 
Error: No valid responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an error:
Error: transaction returned with failure: 
ValidationException: Instance org.evotedapp.biznet.ResultCount#el9888210 missing required field votes`enter code here`
```

Comment: i get that the error is coming because of vote attribute is missing. my understanding is it's not setting value because of query is not working as i expected. Can someone show me what went wrong in here. it's clearly I've done something stupid.

Comment: Have you tried query with `await`?